# Import 2 or more columns from Excel into 1 column Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have an Excel report that is the output of an opinion tool. In this Excel I have all the responses that the people submit for my quizz, in the questions that are multiple choise answer the tool output those questions like one question per option and only the selected option is the column with data in the Excel. For example, if my quizz is like this:

Q1 Your name:

R1 =

Q2 Options

- opt 1
- opt 2
- opt 3

The Excel report will appear like this

[Excel Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f21H.png)

So I want that when I import the Excel to Access it can automatically merge those columns to have only to headers in the Access table: "Q1 Your name:" & "Q2 Options"

Also, for context of the job, I will make some other editions to that imported table and then copy to another Access table (table 2) so even if there is a way to merge those Access columns before copy to the another one I will accept it like, I don't know, insert from this column and if empty insert from that column, I'm not good at doing queries sorry. Only the table 2 will have information, the first table would be like a temporary one so I will daily delete information from that one and preserve the important data en the table 2

Thanks for the support

Comment: Can you show me the input excel file that you are using ? So it will be more clear. Also what you tried for doing this merging, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can see to achieve your goal is to concatenate the three columns; since by the sound of it you will only ever have a value in one column per question per record. You could do this in Excel prior to the import, you could use a calculated field on the table or you could build a query that concatenates all your questions. My suggestion would be Excel since using the `=CONCATENATE()` function is probably going to be easiest option for you.

If you do import your raw data into Access you will need to assign unique column names, ie Q2_Op1, Q2_Op2, Q2_Op3.

The query syntax to concatenate these fields one would be something like:

```
 SELECT Q1_Name, [Q2_Op1] & [Q2_Op2] & [Q3_Op3] AS Q2_Options
 FROM Table1;
```

Where Q1_Name, Q2_Op1, Q2_Op2, Q3_Op3 are the column names on the imported data table.